# Update Marker position with Animation in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I have successfully fetched the Latitude and Longitude from some data stored in the Database. But I am unable to update the marker location on the map. Can please someone help me with the code or as to how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using `CameraUpdate` ,

```
LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng); //Store these lat lng values somewhere. These should be constant.
CameraUpdate location = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 15);
mMap.animateCamera(location);
```

Or can also use this,

```
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());  
     MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions(); 
     markerOptions.position(latLng); 
     markerOptions.title(totalAddress); //Here Total Address is address which you want to show on marker
     mMap.clear();


     markerOptions.icon(
     BitmapDescriptorFactory
    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)); 

     markerOptions.getPosition(); 
     mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions); 
     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
     mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
```

Comment: Is the getPosition() method to get the device's location in which I am testing the Map??

Comment: No Actually I thing You already have Latitude and Longitude as you mentioned in post. This  `markerOptions.getPosition()`  will returns the one that we have set above it using  `markerOptions.position(latLng)` .That's it not for current location of device.